# How get the columns of table where column of datatype int is null?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select * from tblCustomerAdmin 
where  ReqCon=null or ReqCon=0
```

Even though I've got data where `ReqCon` =`NULL`, I'm not getting any rows displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from tblCustomerAdmin where ReqCon is NULL or ReqCon =0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a value is `NULL` you have to use `IS NULL`, because comparison operators (`=`, `!=`) return `UNKNOWN` if either or both arguments are `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomerAdmin 
WHERE ReqCon IS NULL OR ReqCon=0
```